# How can I implement pinch-in / pinch-out with Ionic?

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework, pinch, ion-content

I use Ionic4 and Angular8.

I want to pinch-in / pinch-out the screen on a smartphone.

What i tried
The following description has been added to index.html.

```html
<meta name = "viewport" content = "viewport-fit = cover, width = device-width, initial-scale = 1.0, minimum-scale = 1.0, maximum-scale = 4.0, user-scalable = yes" />
```

But contrary to expectations, it did not work on the actual machine.

I also tried.

The following has been added to .

```js
scrollX = "true"
```

Then you can now pinch-in / pinch-out the screen on your smartphone.
But I don't know why or why.

Also, if the height of  is large enough to require vertical scrolling
I cannot scroll horizontally after pinch-in the screen.

I don't know why.
I want to make horizontal scrolling work after screen enlargement.

Please let me know if anyone knows how.

Comment: do you mean you wan to zoom in and zoom out ?

Comment: Yes.I want to zoom in and zoom out the screen on a smartphone.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `Pinch zoom for Angular` .

> The module provides opportunities for image zooming in, zooming out and positioning with use of gestures on a touch screen.

[Check out live demo](http://ivylab.space/pinch-zoom) . its easy to install .

1 - Install the npm package.

```
npm i ngx-pinch-zoom
```

2 - Import module in you ts . like `home.module.ts`:

```
import { PinchZoomModule } from 'ngx-pinch-zoom';

@NgModule({
    imports: [ PinchZoomModule ]
})
```

3 - in your html

```
<pinch-zoom>
    <img src="path_to_image" /> 
</pinch-zoom>
```

Comment: Thanks,I was able to zoom in and zoom out the image by following the instructions.

Comment: Is there a way to zoom in and zoom out the whole page, not just the image?

Comment: try to add div including your data if he zooming or not .

Comment: I'm sorry for the late reply.

I didn't know how to apply the above support, so I added scrollX = "true" to ion-content.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

This works in ionic 4+. Tested on ionic 5.

**Pinch to zoom on the entire page or specific div or on image.**

You can do following.

```
<ion-content scrollX="true" scrollY="true">
...your content.
<ion-content>
```

Above method enables pinch to zoom on entire page on web. Not for mobile platforms.

For Mobile platforms.
Install pinch to zoom from - http://ivylab.space/pinch-zoom

or
`npm i ngx-pinch-zoom`

follow [@AliGhassan Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60024765/10015861)  for remaining setup.

Now to enable pinch to zoom on entire web page,
Set the html tags for ionic content as follows in your page.html file

```
<ion-content scrollX="true" scrollY="true">
   <pinch-zoom [properties]="zoomProperties">
     <ion-grid>
       ....contents.. 
     </ion-grid>
   </pinch-zoom>
</ion-content>
```

Create a variable for zoom properties as follows in page.ts file

```
zoomProperties = {
  "double-tap": true, // double tap to zoom in and out.
  "overflow": "hidden",// Am not sure. But Documentation says, it will not render elements outside the container.
  "wheel": false, // Disables mouse - To enable scrolling. Else mouse scrolling will be used to zoom in and out on web.
  "disableZoomControl": "disable", // stops showing zoom + and zoom - images.
  "backgroundColor": "rgba(0,0,0,0)" // Makes the pinch zoom container color to transparent. So that ionic themes can be applied without issues.
 }
```

Now, You should be able to pinch to zoom on mobile platforms as well.

If you are further interested, You can implement the same concept on an image or a div etc.

Thank you :)

Comment: Just a warning: ngx-pinch-zoom is not well maintained. There are some forks for newer versions of angular e.g.: npm i ngx-pinch-zoom-13 will install an angular 13 compatible version. These versions are even less well maintained.

Answer (score 0):

In my case abusing the ion-slides was perfectly fine when using just one image that I want to enlarge / pinch-to-zoom. It also supports double tap, which gives it a smoother flavour of using it.

using vue and ionic for example:

```html
<template>
...
        <ion-slides :options="sliderOptions" zoom>
          <ion-slide>
            <div class="swiper-zoom-container">
              <img :src="`${yourImageUrl}`" />
            </div>
          </ion-slide>
        </ion-slides>
...
</template>
```

if ur using options api, pass in the config object

```js
let sliderOptions = {
  zoom: {
    maxRatio: 2,
  },
};
```

if you then build it and double tap the image or pinch-to-zoom